# solaris 11.3 / 11.4 crash if zfs pool should be imported

Tags: solaris, zfs, raidz

My Solaris 11.3 system had a reboot for whatever reason and since than a zpool is tried to be imported.

Assertion failed: range != 0, file ../../../uts/common/fs/zfs/spa_misc.c, line 1326, function spa_get_random

```
root@solaris:~# zpool import
  pool: mediapool1
    id: 8470162457149274931
state: ONLINE
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier and
        the '-f' flag.
   see: http://support.oracle.com/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
config:



        mediapool1                 ONLINE
          raidz1-0                 ONLINE
            c0t5000C500A2C3F5D9d0  ONLINE
            c0t5000C500A2C40ECEd0  ONLINE
            c0t5000C500A2C4122Bd0  ONLINE
root@solaris:~
```

So it should be importable but isnt. .. -> Kernel Oops

zdb shows some data. So how can I get my data back. HDDs are alive, smartdata a fine.

Is there somebody who wants to help me to getting data back ?

ZDB shows....

```
root@solaris:~# zdb -e -dddd mediapool1
Dataset mediapool1 [ZPL], ID 18, cr_txg 1, 224K, 10 objects, rootbp DVA[0]=<0:903a3a5c000:4000:RZM:3> [L0 DMU objset] fletcher4 lzjb LE unique unencrypted size=800L/200P birth=10836736L/10836736P fill=10 contiguous 3-copy cksum=1416247ffb:6ec9c299cf2:1423227024d05:28fa8c22fe2105



    Deadlist: 0 (0/0 comp)



        mintxg 0 -> obj 21



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         0    7    16K    16K  74.5K    16K   31.25  DMU dnode
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -1    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries



                0 = 0xdf20



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries



                0 = 0xdf20



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         1    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 7 entries



                ROOT = 0x4
                SA_ATTRS = 0x2
                casesensitivity = 0x2
                VERSION = 0x6
                DELETE_QUEUE = 0x3
                SHARES = 0x7
                normalization = 0



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  SA master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 2 entries



                LAYOUTS = 0x6
                REGISTRY = 0x5



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         3    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS delete queue
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries




    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         4    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jun 20 09:39:20 2017
        mtime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        ctime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        crtime  Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        gen     4
        mode    040755
        size    5
        parent  4
        links   5
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 3 entries



                backup = 11 (type: Directory)
                fs_userhome = 10 (type: Directory)
                export = 12 (type: Directory)



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         5    1    16K  1.50K  10.5K  1.50K  100.00  SA attr registration
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 1536 bytes, 21 entries



                ZPL_ZNODE_ACL = 0x5803000f : [88:3:15]
                ZPL_RDEV = 0x800000a : [8:0:10]
                ZPL_LINKS = 0x8000008 : [8:0:8]
                ZPL_ATIME = 0x10000000 : [16:0:0]
                ZPL_GID = 0x800000d : [8:0:13]
                ZPL_PAD = 0x2000000e : [32:0:14]
                ZPL_SCANSTAMP = 0x20030012 : [32:3:18]
                ZPL_SIZE = 0x8000006 : [8:0:6]
                ZPL_UID = 0x800000c : [8:0:12]
                ZPL_CTIME = 0x10000002 : [16:0:2]
                ZPL_MAC_LABEL = 0x30014 : [0:3:20]
                ZPL_MTIME = 0x10000001 : [16:0:1]
                ZPL_MODE = 0x8000005 : [8:0:5]
                ZPL_FLAGS = 0x800000b : [8:0:11]
                ZPL_PARENT = 0x8000007 : [8:0:7]
                ZPL_DACL_ACES = 0x40013 : [0:4:19]
                ZPL_CRTIME = 0x10000003 : [16:0:3]
                ZPL_SYMLINK = 0x30011 : [0:3:17]
                ZPL_GEN = 0x8000004 : [8:0:4]
                ZPL_DACL_COUNT = 0x8000010 : [8:0:16]
                ZPL_XATTR = 0x8000009 : [8:0:9]



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         6    1    16K    16K  21.5K    32K  100.00  SA attr layouts
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 1
        Fat ZAP stats:
                Pointer table:
                        1024 elements
                        zt_blk: 0
                        zt_numblks: 0
                        zt_shift: 10
                        zt_blks_copied: 0
                        zt_nextblk: 0
                ZAP entries: 1
                Leaf blocks: 1
                Total blocks: 2
                zap_block_type: 0x8000000000000001
                zap_magic: 0x2f52ab2ab
                zap_salt: 0x32d772cd
                Leafs with 2^n pointers:
                        9:      1 *
                Blocks with n*5 entries:
                        0:      1 *
                Blocks n/10 full:
                        1:      1 *
                Entries with n chunks:
                        4:      1 *
                Buckets with n entries:
                        0:    511 ****************************************
                        1:      1 *



                2 = [ 5  6  4  12  13  7  11  0  1  2  3  8  16  19 ]



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         7    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /.zfs/shares
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Wed Jun 14 08:43:53 2017
        mtime   Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        ctime   Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        crtime  Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        gen     4
        mode    040555
        size    2
        parent  7
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries




    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        10    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /fs_userhome
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Fri Dec 21 06:21:30 2018
        mtime   Fri Jun 16 13:07:27 2017
        ctime   Fri Jun 16 13:07:27 2017
        crtime  Fri Jun 16 13:07:27 2017
        gen     20775
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries




    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        11    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /backup
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Fri Dec 21 06:21:30 2018
        mtime   Sat Jun 17 13:47:04 2017
        ctime   Sat Jun 17 13:47:04 2017
        crtime  Sat Jun 17 13:47:04 2017
        gen     39220
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries




    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        12    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /export
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jan 29 06:46:27 2019
        mtime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        ctime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        crtime  Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        gen     39413
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries




root@solaris:~# zdb -e -dddd mediapool1/export
Dataset mediapool1/export [ZPL], ID 879, cr_txg 37449, 202K, 8 objects, rootbp DVA[0]=<0:903a39cc000:4000:RZM:3> [L0 DMU objset] fletcher4 lzjb LE unique unencrypted size=800L/200P birth=10836735L/10836735P fill=8 contiguous 3-copy cksum=1695577b35:7cf5a5fbca5:16bf5de66c79d:2e4ab1d9943912



    Deadlist: 107K (9.00K/9.00K comp)



        mintxg 0 -> obj 217
        mintxg 1 -> obj 218
        mintxg 37455 -> obj 219



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         0    7    16K    16K  74.5K    16K   25.00  DMU dnode
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -1    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries



                0 = 0x85e0



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries



                0 = 0x85e0



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         1    1    16K     1K  10.5K     1K  100.00  ZFS master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 1024 bytes, 8 entries



                SA_ATTRS = 0x2
                DELETE_QUEUE = 0x3
                SHARES = 0x7
                casesensitivity = 0x2
                normalization = 0
                VERSION = 0x5
                utf8only = 0
                ROOT = 0x4



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  SA master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 2 entries



                REGISTRY = 0x5
                LAYOUTS = 0x6



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         3    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS delete queue
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries




    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         4    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jan 29 06:46:27 2019
        mtime   Wed May 20 16:50:07 2015
        ctime   Wed May 20 16:50:07 2015
        crtime  Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        gen     65199
        mode    040755
        size    3
        parent  4
        links   3
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries



                home = 8 (type: Directory)



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         5    1    16K  1.50K  10.5K  1.50K  100.00  SA attr registration
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 1536 bytes, 21 entries



                ZPL_GID = 0x800000d : [8:0:13]
                ZPL_DACL_ACES = 0x40013 : [0:4:19]
                ZPL_CRTIME = 0x10000003 : [16:0:3]
                ZPL_MAC_LABEL = 0x30014 : [0:3:20]
                ZPL_ATIME = 0x10000000 : [16:0:0]
                ZPL_SIZE = 0x8000006 : [8:0:6]
                ZPL_LINKS = 0x8000008 : [8:0:8]
                ZPL_PAD = 0x2000000e : [32:0:14]
                ZPL_PARENT = 0x8000007 : [8:0:7]
                ZPL_MODE = 0x8000005 : [8:0:5]
                ZPL_DACL_COUNT = 0x8000010 : [8:0:16]
                ZPL_SYMLINK = 0x30011 : [0:3:17]
                ZPL_XATTR = 0x8000009 : [8:0:9]
                ZPL_SCANSTAMP = 0x20030012 : [32:3:18]
                ZPL_UID = 0x800000c : [8:0:12]
                ZPL_GEN = 0x8000004 : [8:0:4]
                ZPL_RDEV = 0x800000a : [8:0:10]
                ZPL_FLAGS = 0x800000b : [8:0:11]
                ZPL_ZNODE_ACL = 0x5803000f : [88:3:15]
                ZPL_CTIME = 0x10000002 : [16:0:2]
                ZPL_MTIME = 0x10000001 : [16:0:1]



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         6    1    16K    16K  21.5K    32K  100.00  SA attr layouts
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 1
        Fat ZAP stats:
                Pointer table:
                        1024 elements
                        zt_blk: 0
                        zt_numblks: 0
                        zt_shift: 10
                        zt_blks_copied: 0
                        zt_nextblk: 0
                ZAP entries: 1
                Leaf blocks: 1
                Total blocks: 2
                zap_block_type: 0x8000000000000001
                zap_magic: 0x2f52ab2ab
                zap_salt: 0x751fd0cd
                Leafs with 2^n pointers:
                        9:      1 *
                Blocks with n*5 entries:
                        0:      1 *
                Blocks n/10 full:
                        1:      1 *
                Entries with n chunks:
                        4:      1 *
                Buckets with n entries:
                        0:    511 ****************************************
                        1:      1 *



                2 = [ 5  6  4  12  13  7  11  0  1  2  3  8  16  19 ]



    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         7    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /.zfs/shares
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Wed Mar  4 06:30:06 2015
        mtime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        ctime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        crtime  Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        gen     65199
        mode    040555
        size    2
        parent  7
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries




    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         8    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /home
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jan 29 06:46:27 2019
        mtime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:32 2013
        ctime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:32 2013
        crtime  Wed Mar 13 21:27:32 2013
        gen     65206
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries
```

Comment: Please stop spamming the various Stackexchange forums with this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857925/solaris-zfs-pool-import-crash  I also seem to remember this was posted to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ last week, but that seems to have been deleted after you ignored several requests for more information.

Comment: Sorry didnt know that there are kept together... Just tried to reach out. Just added crashdumps on the referenced one

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the zpool is not used by another host. You can force the import with the -f option

Comment: As far as I remeber this was crashing as well. In the meantime a data recovery company restored nearly everything. But they told me a bit about the issue and that was a lot of manual work. And yes I trust them we're good friends.